# When printing characters, how do I change where I'm printing (printing all bytes on same spot)?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I need to go byte by byte (I can't just do the string print, with offset grades in dx) and I can't find what I need anywhere, most people just use the print string, so after I print a char, how do I move to the next square in the dosbox? It's printing them all in the same spot, so it just shows me the last digit...

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
grades db '90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98'
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 26
    mov ah, 09h 
    mov bh, 0   
    mov si, 0
printcolor: 
    mov bl, 00000010b
    mov al, [grades + si]
    push cx
    mov cx, 1
    int 10h
    pop cx
    inc si
    loop printcolor
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html - 09 is "write char at cursor", so check "2 - set cursor position" ... or check how the EGA/VGA text modes have memory organized and write directly to `B800:0000` area.

Answer (score 0):

### BIOS function 09h does not advance the cursor.

1. If you *don't really need* the Green On Black color then you could just use the Teletype function 0Eh instead as an easy fix.

   ```
    mov  cx, 26 
    mov  bh, 0   
    mov  si, 0
   printcolor: 
    mov  bl, 00000010b
    mov  al, [grades + si]
    mov  ah, 0Eh
    int  10h
    inc  si
    loop printcolor
   ```
2. If you *do insist on* the Green On Black color, then use both these functions together. Function 09h will provide the desired color, function 0Eh will give the cursor advancement.

   ```
    mov  bh, 0   
    mov  cx, 1
    mov  si, 0
   printcolor: 
    mov  bl, 00000010b
    mov  al, [grades + si]
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  10h
    mov  ah, 0Eh
    int  10h
    inc  si
    cmp  si, 26
    jb   printcolor
   ```

   Note that in the 2nd example I've avoided the double using of `CX` (thereby eliminating the `push` and `pop`) by using the offset in `SI` for finding out if 26 characters were processed.